# Solr - change default facet order for front-end

Tags: solr, facet

I"m very new to Solr so pls forgive my ignorance if this question is too simplistic. i'm having issue where the facets are working fine but due to nature of the products the default order of Numeric-Alpha isn't ideal. Scenario: site is for jewlelry and Rings come in numeric sizes 5, 6,7 etc and S, M, L, XL. The problem is with the alphas -- i want it to be is size order not alpha so right now XS is appearing at end but I want it to appear before S. XL is above XS but I want XS to be first and XL to be last etc. Make sense? Any ideas on how to customize and make it the desired size order?

Current: 5,6,7,8, M, L, One Size, S, XL, XS
Desired: 5, 6,7, 8, XS, S, M, L, XL, One Size

Answer (score 1):

Solr only provides facet sorting by either count or alpha-numeric. Since you have a low amount of unique values in your facet, you could get the full result set (facet.limit=-1) and sort client-side.

Another solution would be to prefix your sizes by prepending an ordering letter: a5, b6, c7, d8, eXS, fS, gM, hL, iXL, jOne Size and ask for facet.order=index. When you get your result, remove the first letter from each term.